# Contradictions in articles about renormalizability of Einstein-conformal gravity

Tags: general-relativity, action, modified-gravity

**Background:** In the calculations I've done, I've found an action of the following form:
\begin{equation}
S=\int d^4x\,\sqrt{-g}\left( \xi^2R+\frac{1}{120}\xi^2C_{\alpha \beta \mu \nu}C^{\alpha \beta \mu \nu}-\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu \nu}\partial_\mu \Phi \partial_\nu \Phi- 16\xi^2\left(1-e^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}\xi}\Phi} \right)^2\right).\tag{1}
\end{equation}
Which is Einstein-conformal gravity with a scalar field having a Starobinsky-like potential. I'm interested in the renormalizability of the gravitational part of this action.

**Problem:** I've come across two papers that state contradictory facts about the renormalizability of this type of model. The first one is [Renormalization of Higher Derivative Quantum Gravity](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/235472686_Renormalization_of_Higher_Derivative_Quantum_Gravity) by K. Stelle. The action which is used in this paper is written:
\begin{equation}
I_{sym}= -\int d^4x\,\sqrt{-g}\left(\alpha R_{\mu \nu}R^{\mu\nu} -\beta R^2+\kappa^{-2}\gamma R\right).\tag{2}
\end{equation}
One can use the formula
\begin{equation}
C_{\alpha \beta \mu \nu}C^{\alpha \beta \mu \nu}=2R_{\mu \nu}R^{\mu \nu}-\frac{2}{3}R^2+G,\tag{3}
\end{equation}
where $G$ is the Chern-Gauss-Bonnet density, to convert the gravitational part of $(1)$ into the form $(2)$. In the last paragraph of the section $3$, the following is stated:

1. *For most values of the parameter $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in $I_{sym}$ it (the propagator) satisfies the requirement that all its leading parts fall off like $k^{-4}$ at large momenta. There are, however, specific choices of these parameters which must be avoided. [...]. Likewise, if $3\beta-\alpha=0$, the massive scalar excitation disappears, and there are again terms in the propagates which behave like $k^{-2}$. Unfortunately, even if we avoid the special cases $\alpha=0$ and $3\beta-\alpha=0$, and if we use the propagator derived from $(3.7)$, we still do not obtain a clean renormalization of the Green's functions.*

So I thought the gravitational part of $(1)$ was not renormalizable, as I have $3\beta-\alpha=0$. However, I've found the paper [Renormalizable 4D Quantum Gravity as A
Perturbed Theory from CFT](https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.3969) by K. Hamada that uses the action
\begin{equation}
I=\int d^4x\,\sqrt{-g} \left( \frac{1}{t^2}C_{\alpha \beta \mu \nu}C^{\alpha \beta \mu \nu}-bG+\frac{1}{\hbar}\left( \frac{1}{16\pi G_N}R-\Lambda+\mathcal{L}_M \right) \right), \tag{4}
\end{equation}
where $t$ and $b$ are dimentionless constants. It is stated in page $2$ that this model is renormalizable:

2. *Thus the renormalizable quantum gravity is defined by the following dimensionless action (I).*

I'm quite confused as these claims seem contradictory at first sight...

**Questions:** Have I misunderstood the claims $1.$ and $2.$, so the gravitational part of $(1)$ is in fact renormalizable? As I write this question I think that maybe the prescription $(3.7)$ in the first article must be changed into $(8.9)$ in the same article, as it changes the propagator, but I'm not sure about this. If anyone has an idea about this...